# Why can't I extend sda5 partition?

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox, gparted

I'm running Ubuntu on Oracle VM VirtualBox. The VM was initially set up with 8GB of storage but now I've run out of space. I used VirtualBox's `vboxmanage modifymedium` function to resize the virtual disk, and I can see the unallocated space in GParted. Now I'm trying to extend the partition sda5 but I don't seem to get the option to extend it out into the unallocated portion of the drive. What am I missing here?

[image: GParted screenshot]

Comment: Install `system-config-lvm` and use the GUI to resize.

Comment: @heynnema, well, that will be helpful to grow the LVM logical volumes after resizing the partition, but that still needs done first with gparted.

Comment: Since sda5 is inside an *extended* partition sda2, you'll have to extend sda2 first, using gparted.

Comment: Cool, so I DID manage to extend sda2 and (subsequently sda5) using GParted by booting in a GParted iso disk. VirtualBox now reports that my drive is 24.41GB, but right-clicking Computer and hitting Properties in Ubuntu tells me I have 6.8GB.

Using system-config-lvm, I see that there's a:
root: Linear Mapping, 1669 extents;
swap_1: Linear Mapping 256 extents; and
unused space: 4202 extents.

I don't know what to make of this... I was expecting Ubuntu to tell me that the Computer has a capacity of 24GB.

Comment: Now you have to use system-config-lvm to resize the logical volume.

Answer (score 1):

sda5 is a logical partition that exists inside sda2, so you need to grow sda2 first.